# Can one apply absolute value to both sides of an inequality?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Can I   claim this:
$$c>b  \implies |c|>|b|$$  with $c>0$? I ask  because I want to use it in a proof but I am not sure. Thank You.

Comment: Counter example:$ 4 > (-15)$ but $|4|<|-15|$

Comment: Thanks I am sorry, I did not needed I needed the reverse triangle inequality that has $||$ in one part of the inequality and that save me  :)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Example, $c=1$, and $b=-2$